# How to access service mediaplayer in other class?

Tags: java, android, service, android-mediaplayer

I created a mediaplayer object in a class that extends Service to play sound in the background, but now i made another class to handle play/pause.

How do i access the same mediaplayer object from my service class?

**Service class**

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

    callStateListener();

    registerNoisyBroadcastReceiver();

    registerNewSongBroadCastReceiver();

    registerPlayActionBroadcastReceiver();

    registerPauseActionBroadcastReceiver();
}
```

**Song activity class (where i want to access the mediaplayer object i use in service)**

```
mBtnPlayPause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                if (mediaPlayer != null) {
                    if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                        pauseSong();
                        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_play);
                    } else {
                        resumeSong();
                        updateProgressBar();
                        mBtnPlayPause.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_action_pause_white);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
```

- mediaPlayer here doesn't work?

Comment: Use basics of java . If static you can access it with class name . If non-static you need an object to access it .

Comment: public static MediaPlayer mediaPlayer like this?

Comment: And then import it in other class right?